# Preparing input data to run bfastSpatial & bfast

Tags: r

I want to identify breakpoints for the whole NDVI time series and then show magnitude and frequency of the breakpoints. My input data is a daily NDVI time series in .tif format. Each image is named by its date (20031002, 20031101, 20031201, …). I use this code to prepare my data but I am faced with an error. In advance, I appreciate your time.

```
setwd("…/ndvi")
list.grid<-list.files(pattern = ".tif$", recursive = TRUE)
d <- c("20000101","20000102","20000103","20000104","20000105", …) 
saveRDS(d, file = "dates.rds")
date_NDVI<-readRDS("dates.rds")
NDVI_S <- raster::stack(list.grid)
NDVI_S<-setZ(NDVI_S,as.Date(date_NDVI$date),name="time")
bfmSpatial(NDVI_S, start=c(2000,1), order=1, mc.cores=8,returnLayers = c("breakpoint", "magnitude", "error"))
```

Error in date_NDVI$date : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Hi Mahsa! Welcome to StackOverflow. What is `date_NDVI`? run `dput(date_NDVI)` and paste the results into your question. Thanks!

Comment: It might be easier to help if you could share part of the `NDVI_S ` and `d` objects, using `dput` as @Mark mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you posted means that `date_NDVI` is already a vector, so you do not need to use an `$` operator to access the dates (this would be the case if `date_NDVI` was a data.frame). Then, you just need to indicate the format in which the dates are given (using `as.Date`) and set them as a Z value (using `setZ`). Finally, you shoud be able to run the bfast analysis.

```
library(raster)
library(bfastSpatial)

setwd("…/ndvi")
list.grid <- list.files(pattern = ".tif$", recursive = TRUE)
d <- c("20000101","20000102","20000103","20000104","20000105", …) 
NDVI_S <- raster::stack(list.grid)
NDVI_S <- setZ(NDVI_S, as.Date(d, format = "%Y%m%d"), name="time")
# Check the start date and mc.cores values (windows OS do not accept mc.cores >1) 
resul <- bfmSpatial(NDVI_S, start=c(2005,1), order=1, mc.cores=8,returnLayers = c("breakpoint", "magnitude", "error"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that the three outputs of bfmSpatial are NA. I appreciate if you could guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes you get NA in the outputs, because you have very few observations to fit the models or to detect changes. You can make sure you use enough observations by testing the bfast algorithm over a few pixels.